# Access static variable from non static method in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, static

I know that you cannot access a non static class variable from within a static context, but what about the other way around? I have the following code:

```
class MyClass {

    static var myArr = [String]()

    func getArr() -> [String] {
        return myArr
    }
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get the error `MyClass does not have a member named myArr`. I thought static variables were visible to both static and non static methods, so I don't know where I am going wrong.

I am on a Macbook running OS X Yosemite using Xcode 6.3.

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax for swift, but try something like return MyClass.myArr

Comment: @SvetlanaSlutstokyovich: Make that an answer to earn some swift(!) points – oops, too late :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the class name before the variable.

```
class MyClass {

    static var myArr = [String]()

    func getArr() -> [String] {
        return MyClass.myArr
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be a problem when `myArr` gets overwritten in a `MyChildClass`, `getArr()` will return value defined in `MyClass`, not in `MyChildClass`.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift3, dynamicType is deprecated. You can use type(of: )

```
struct SomeData {
  static let name = "TEST"
}

let data = SomeData()
let name = type(of:data).name
// it will print TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the class name.

```
class MyClass {

    static var myArr = [String]()

    func getArr() -> [String] {
        return MyClass.myArr
    }

}
```

You could access you Array from two different ways:

```
MyClass().getArr()
```

or

```
MyClass.myArr
```

Comment: Is using self.myArr an acceptable way to do this as well?

Comment: Just from a class method and you don't need self explicitly

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `self.dynamicType`:

```
class MyClass {

    static var myArr = [String]()

    func getArr() -> [String] {
        return self.dynamicType.myArr
    }
}
```