# Swift: Why the non-static methods can't call static variables and constant (static let) without dynamicType?

Tags: swift, swift2, constants, static-members, dynamictype

It has destroyed my view about static variables and constant after using swift.

Why swift doesn't allow us to call static variables and constant in other methods?

for example:

```
class Aa {
    static let name = "Aario"
    func echo() {
        print(name)      // Error!
    } 
}
```

Mr. ogres told me to use `dynamicType` .

```
class Aa {
    static var name = "Aario"
    func echo() {
        print(self.dynamicType.name)
    }
}

let a = Aa()
a.dynamicType.name = "Aario Ai"   
a.echo()                         // it works!!!
```

It works! So why should I use dynamicType to call static variables?

Finally, the answer is:

```
class Aa {
    static var name = "Static Variable"
    var name = "Member Variable"
    func echo() {
        print(self.dynamicType.name)    // Static Variable
        print(Aa.name)                  // Static Variable
        print(name)                     // Member Variable
    }
}

let a = Aa()
a.dynamicType.name = "Aario Ai"   
Aa.name = "Static: Aario"
a.name = "Member: Aario"
a.echo()                         // it works!!!
```

It's really different with other languages.

Comment: use self.dynamictype.name

Comment: You are right. Can you tell me why it's quite different with other languages?

Comment: You can have both an instance property and a type (class/static) property with the same name.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168069/access-static-variable-from-non-static-method-in-swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables have to be addressed with their type, even when you're writing code within this type. See [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2) - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) (in "Querying and Setting Type Properties"):

> Type properties are queried and set with dot syntax, just like instance properties. However, type properties are queried and set on the type, not on an instance of that type.

In your code, simply write  `Aa.name` instead of `name` and you'll be fine.